# Android build stopped working with ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, rider

Currently trying to update my update my app with the latest packages. It builds just fine but when i wanna start it i erorrs out with the following:

```
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/dk.app-k28yLNqyqYP2YJG6gblFsA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/dk.app-k28yLNqyqYP2YJG6gblFsA==/lib/x86, /data/app/app-k28yLNqyqYP2YJG6gblFsA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6988)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6528)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6445)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/dk.app-k28yLNqyqYP2YJG6gblFsA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/dk.app-k28yLNqyqYP2YJG6gblFsA==/lib/x86, /data/app/dk.app-k28yLNqyqYP2YJG6gblFsA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(:62)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6972)
06-03 11:24:47.852 E/AndroidRuntime( 5672):     ... 10 more
```

I googled a bit and found out about AdMob, but I am not using that in this app at all. I am kinda lost :( Anyone has any idea? I am using Android API 29 and Xamarin in this project! All I did was updating all my NuGet packages to their latest respective versions.

Comment: What packages are you using? Also, you can try to pinpoint which package is the troublesome, when you upgrade the packages 1 by 1 and after each update, you try to deploy the app.

Comment: @MihailDuchev I have updated all the packages already, so i dont know how to REVERT that haha. im using around 155 packages. And I have troubles finding the one in question